# Can't create multiple instances of Geometry Drawing

Tags: wpf, xaml

Icons in my application are stored as geometry drawings in a resource dicitony. for example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Viewbox x:Key="ViewboxIconClose"
         Width="16"
         Height="16">
    <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1M9.4141,8L13.9571,12.543 12.5431,13.957 8.0001,9.414 3.4571,13.957 2.0431,12.543 6.5861,8 2.0431,3.457 3.4571,2.043 8.0001,6.586 12.5431,2.043 13.9571,3.457z" />
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Viewbox>
```

This icon is used like this:

```
<Button>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="ViewboxIconClose" />
</Button>
```

Now my Problem:
if i use this geometry somewhere else, it will only work at one place. for example if i use this geometry in a menu, the geometry on the button will disapear in the moment, i open the menu.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use x:Shared=false to solve this but I'd probably use a style and an image instead. The image should be more efficient than a rectangle with a brush and a viewbox.

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"

    xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CloseIcon" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
        <Setter Property="Source">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingImage PresentationOptions:Freeze="True">
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1M9.4141,8L13.9571,12.543 12.5431,13.957 8.0001,9.414 3.4571,13.957 2.0431,12.543 6.5861,8 2.0431,3.457 3.4571,2.043 8.0001,6.586 12.5431,2.043 13.9571,3.457z" />
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Height="100" Width="100" Background="Red">
            <Image  Style="{StaticResource CloseIcon}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="30" Width="30" Background="Blue">
            <Image  Style="{StaticResource CloseIcon}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

With this specific requirement you could just use one geometry as data for a path. Geometries aren't visuals.